# jQuery carousel slider stays in front of lightbox image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, lightbox

I'm very new to jQuery so only using the plug ins at the moment. I have downloaded a carousel slider which you manually slide, to view images with text information underneath, then you can click on more (at the bottom of the image/text box) and another box slides to the right  with more info etc. I then added text links to this box that slides out to enable the visitor to see the images bigger using the light box plugin.

When I click the text link to open light box (to see the image bigger), the carousel text box that slid out stays in place (over the light box image) so I have to manually click the 'x' in the corner of the carousel box to view the image...

Does anyone have any thoughts on the sort of code I would need to implement into this... would it be adding code to the .js file of the carousel to tell it to close when lightbox is in use????? if so PLEASE what kinda thing would it be?

Answer (score 0):

Try to find the css classes of your lightbox popup and of your carrosel and set the biggest z-index  to lightbox div and a not so bigger to the carrosel div. In this way the first will appear over the last one.

Comment: thank you so much, googled z index and went from there as never heard of it before! worked perfectly!